# Roots of a quadratic function: math domain error

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, square-root

I want to define a function that returns the values of the roots. It is supposed to return always something.

If b**2 - 4*a*c < 0, then it is supposed to return [ ], but it appears as an error.

My code is this by now:

```
    from math import*
    def solve(a, b, c):
        x = sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)

        if x > 0:
           x1 = (-b + x)/(2*a)
           x2 = (-b - x)/(2*a)
           return [x1, x2]

        elif x == 0:
           x1 = x2 = -b/(2*a)
           return [x1]

       else:
           return []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqrt` will not accept negative values. To avoid this, you can check your 'else' condition before computing the square root:

```
from math import sqrt

def solve(a, b, c):
    
    formula = b**2 - 4*a*c

    if formula < 0:
       return []

    x = sqrt(formula)

    if x > 0:
       x1 = (-b + x)/(2*a)
       x2 = (-b - x)/(2*a)
       return [x1, x2]

    elif x == 0:
       x1 = x2 = -b/(2*a)
       return [x1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `math.sqrt` is undefined for negative numbers and thus returns a `ValueError`.

If you wish to return the complex square root for negatives, use `x**0.5`:

```
x = (b**2 - 4*a*c)**0.5
```

Alternatively use the `cmath.sqrt` implementation:

```
from cmath import sqrt

x = sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)
```

Comment: I got it, the problem now is that ' ' > ' is not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'int' ', so it means that I would have to change all code, isn't it? Anyway, I don't need the complex root, I only need [ ] as return when b**2 - 4*a*c < 0, but advice appears always.

Comment: well yeah... you'll need to change your code